# Transferring slides from one computer to another and the images are lost

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-impress

I used OpenOffice Impress to make some slides for a presentation and when I try to transfer the slides to another computer the images are lost, with text displayed in their place describing the location that the images could be found. This happens when I save in odp and ppt and also when I try to upload the slides to Google Docs.

Any idea what is wrong?

While making the slides I just dragged and dropped the images into the presentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you drag and drop images into OpenOffice, it creates links rather than embedding them.

To make them embedded, go to the **Edit** menu, choose **Links**, highlight all the links for images that you want to have embedded, and click the **Break Link** button.

For future documents, if you add images through the **Insert, Picture, From File** menu instead of through drag and drop, they'll be embedded right away, so you won't have to go through this step.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell it to "include all external resources" in the file. I don't know what the button name for this would be, but a quick search will probably help you out.

Comment: I can't find this in the help.

Answer (score 0):

yeah, your images are strictly pointers... the images aren't actually part of the file, the file just references the images (as stored external to the file). You can move the images over with the file (and then relink them to their new locations on the new computer) or export the file in a way that includes all the resources (making the file size larger, but fully self contained).

Comment: I want to upload this to slideshare or google docs, so moving the images won't work unless I put them all online I suppose, but I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Insert -> Picture -> From File.. works